# How to embed the data in the Analysis DXP file?

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-webplayer

I am trying to figure out how to embed the data to the DXP file when the user downloads the DXP file by going to the Web Player and presses **File** -> **Download as DXP File** option.

Currently, when the user downloads the file locally and opens it, they get prompted for the "Data Connection" credentials:

[image]

I am assuming that is because our data is accessed via database and it is not embedded into the DXP file itself. I have 2 questions:

1. How to make it so that the data is embedded into the DXP file so the
   user doesn't have to log in using the  "Data Connection"
   credentials?
2. Is it possible to only embed that data when the user
   downloads the DXP file using the **File** -> **Download as DXP
   File** option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, click Edit then Data Table Properties. On the General tab, select "Embedded in analysis" under Store data.

I don't know the answer to your second question.

What I normally do is save a version of the DXP locally that has all the correct connections. I then manually save copy as a library item when the data needs to be updated. When you do this, it gives you the option to embed the data in the library item version of the DXP. It isn't the best solution if the data needs to be updated frequently.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. That does make sense. I will investigate how I can embed the data

Comment: to add, there is no method out of the box to automatically embed only when a user downloads a DXP. if they are using the Analyst, I believe the user gets a prompt about how the data is saved, but it may not pop for Data Connections.

Comment: @niko Thanks for the comment. Can I ask if I change my analysis file so that it has the data source embedded to it, the user won't be prompted to log in, am I right?

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev If there is no connection to a database, I would think that a user wouldn't be prompted to login to one.

Comment: @blakeoft is correct. if you embed the data, no connection to the database is required since it's saved in the .dxp itself.

Comment: Thank you both! Yes, that does make sense. Would it be fair to say that the resulting DXP file could become very big if I embed all of the data I have? (this is probably a rhetorical question)